# when using compressobj and trying to flush it does not return anything

Tags: python, zlib

I am trying to learn zlib and when I was trying to learn the decompressobj and use flush() to add at it to an empty bytes variable it doesnt work

```
import zlib
item='this is a test string'
decompressor=zlib.decompressobj(wbits=15)
comp=zlib.compress(item)
decomp=bytes('',encoding='utf-8')
decompressor.decompress(comp)
decomp+=decompressor.flush()
print(decomp)
```

the code prints out

```
b''
```

Comment: Looks like all of the data was actually produced by the call to `.decompress()` in this case - which you threw away rather than saving.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comment, you forgot to put in `decomp+=` before `decompressor.decompress(comp)`.

Also you need a `b` before `'this is a test string'`.